# How to make hits of caps-lock get ignored unless also pressing shift?

Tags: macos, keybindings

I want to prevent accidental presses of Caps Lock by configuring it to toggle only when you press shift at the same time. Is there a way to do that? I don't mind if I have to use the terminal to do this, but I'd prefer not to have to install 3rd party software.

Please note what I'm asking for pertains to what happens when you hold shift (or not) just when hitting the caps-lock key. The way caps-lock changes the behaviour of other keys wrt shift is a different question.